# Warning of class sharing doesnt allow me to profile locally (Windows) using visualVM

Tags: windows, eclipse, java-6, visualvm, jvisualvm

When I launch my java app from Eclipse Helios I see it in the list of local applications on the visualVM.  However, I go to the Profiler tab and I can't profile either by CPU or Memory criteria.

I get the following message:
"WARNING! Class sharing is enabled for this JVM. This can cause problems when profiling the application and eventually may crash it. Please see the VisualVM Troubleshooting Guide for more information and steps to fix the problem: https://visualvm.dev.java.net/troubleshooting.html#xshare."

In the eclipse launcher of my app, I added -Xshare:off to the VM_Arguments with no success.
JDK Used: jdk 1.6.0_20 
Enviornment: Windows 7, 64bit

Any advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does you Eclipse require UAC permission to run?? I bet it does...

**Just run VisualVM as an Administrator** so that they will run under the same user.

Cheers!
Marco

Comment: Hi Marco!
You are right! that was the missing part! Thanks a lot.. its now working!